# travis-ci failing to deploy to sonatype

Tags: travis-ci, nexus, sonatype

I've started using travis-ci to automate my builds. I have several open source projects and they all deploy to nexus sonatype from where they go to maven central. They're all Java projects that use Maven to build and github as a repo. 
I've been doing this manually for years and I have appropriate keys and logins and my pom is compatible etc.
Implementing the first one was easy enough, it is a [single module project](https://github.com/RogerParkinson/madura-ampq) and it builds and deploys just fine. Then I did a second one, [a multi module project](https://github.com/RogerParkinson/madura-objects-parent) and got that working in much the same way. My third, however, is baffling me.
The maven build on this thing is a bit tricky but it does run fine locally and I even have it running the actual build on travis successfully. But the deploy doesn't work.
The problem is that when it tries to connect to nexus sonatype I get an authorisation error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project madura-bundles: 
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact nz.co.senanque:madura-bundles:pom:4.5.6 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): 
Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/nz/co/senanque/madura-bundles/4.5.6/madura-bundles-4.5.6.pom.
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

It looks like I have not set up my sonatype credentials correctly. But I have set it up the same way as I did for the other two projects. Specifically I go into Nexus Sonatype and get my Access User Token and add those to my environment (SONATYPE_USERNAME and SONATYPE_PASSWORD, I deleted both of these and re-entered them in case it was a typo). I also add references to those in my local maven settings file:

```
...
<server>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <username>${env.SONATYPE_USERNAME}</username>
    <password>${env.SONATYPE_PASSWORD}</password>
</server>
...
```

The local maven settings file is a file in my project and the .travis.yml maven commands refer to it. The [travis.yml](https://github.com/RogerParkinson/madura-ampq/blob/master/.travis.yml) file has a deploy section identical to the other two (working) projects, except I have been adding extra bits to try and make it work. But none of the differences there look relevant. The working deploys look like this:

```
deploy:
 provider: script
  script: "mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${TRAVIS_TAG} && mvn clean deploy -B -U -P release --settings travis/settings.xml"
  on:
    tags: true
```

so this is only going to kick off if the repo has been tagged and it uses the tag as the version number. In the other projects this works fine, but not in the one I'm trying to get working. The tag does trigger the deploy as it should, but the deploy fails.
Does anyone know why I get the deploy on one project but not another? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The problem is that the parent pom of the failing project does not have a release profile, the parent pom of the working project does have one. The release profile in both cases looks like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.3</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

It is needed to sign the generated artifacts (jar files, javadoc files etc) with the gpg plugin and to deploy them to nexus. The deploy to nexus is attempted without this but because it didn't have the reference to serverId:ossrh it doesn't pick up credentials from the maven settings file and therefore I get an authorization error.
The release profile needs to be on the parent project and all the module projects. I had added it to the modules but forgot the parent.